# Why won't Webpack refresh the page for my Angular 1.x app on change?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to convert our Gulp-based workflow to webpack, and am having trouble figuring out how to get the live reload functionality to work (auto refresh when any of the javascript changes). My project is an Angular 1.5.8 app with an Express backend, with `jade` markup files compiled to html and `stylus (.styl)` files compiles to `css` through our build step. For now, I'm ONLY transpiling the javascript and bundling it together just to see if I can get that part working, but I can't.

I should note, `index.jade` does NOT get transpiled by our build step. When a user makes a request to our backend, `index.jade` gets compiled to html and served up to the client.

My project structure looks like this

```
- bin (compiled/transpiled files)
  - js
    - index.js(transpiled js)
    - templates.js (created for angular's template cache)
  - stylesheets ( compiled from stylus to css)
    - stylesheet1.css
    - stylesheet2.css
    - ...
  - templates
    - random-html-file.html
    - ...
- lib
    - index.js (this file serves up `index.jade`)
    - server
      - index.js
      - api
         - index.js
    - client (es6 angular code)
      - index.jade
      - javascript
        - index.js (main entry point)
        - restOfAngularStuff
      - stylesheets folder
      - templates folder (jade)
```

Ok so that's basically the file structure (simplified). The `Express` server listens on port `3000` and knows to serve up content from `./bin` (the server is started with `NODE_PATH=./` so from the root directory) I can get the javascript to be transpiled by webpack with this set up in my `webpack.config.js`: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cc1350022175288895ab956036569f94

That file gets called by my npm script `npm run webpack-dev`, which runs `webpack-dev-server`.

The server starts up and my app loads, but when I changed some of the javascript in `lib/client/javascript/index.js`, the page doesn't refresh and I can't seem to figure out why. I'm fairly new to Webpack but I'm willing to provide as much info as I can if anyone needs more info to help me debug this problem. I've also posted the server-side code for how `index.jade` gets served up for reference (`lib/index.js`): https://gist.github.com/anonymous/70c267e6ceddd194b5cd0e6c1c177445

Thanks!

Comment: add `inline: true` in `devServer` and check it

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work. Do I need to set up a proxy server? Also I know that webpack-dev-server keeps changes in memory and doesn't write to disk. My understanding is that it opens up a socket and connects to the browser. If that socket is open, it should say so in my browser console correct (I've seen that in examples)? I don't seem to be getting that. Also just realized that none of the changes, even if I refresh, get applied.

Comment: I got the refresh to work (i think it had to do with some of my vendor files being imported in but not being exported properly) but none of the changes get reflected after the refresh. I think it has something to do with the bundled index.js file being served up and not Webpack Dev Server's in memory version of the compiled javascript.